# "The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity. Parameter name: keyValues" Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So Iv'e used the CRUD operations with Entity Framework in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have made a login form where every unique user gets a UserId, and im trying now to manipulate these CRUD operations so the user can edit or delete it's database record. But I keep getting the error as you see in the title.

I think that it has to do with my primary keys, here's some code:

Model:

```
public partial class TimesheetEntry
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

        public decimal HoursWorked { get; set; }

        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Aviato.Models.TimesheetEntry>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.ProjectName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EntryDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoursWorked)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.ProjectName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoursWorked)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "User")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class TimesheetEntryController : Controller
    {
    private readonly AviatoModel _db = new AviatoModel(); //Database Model

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }

                var timesheetentry = _db.TimesheetEntries.Find(id);

                if (timesheetentry == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(_db.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", timesheetentry.ProjectId);
                ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_db.Users, "UserId", "SocialSecurityNumber", timesheetentry.UserId);

                return View(timesheetentry);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="UserId,ProjectId,EntryDate,HoursWorked")] TimesheetEntry timesheetentry)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _db.Entry(timesheetentry).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(_db.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", timesheetentry.ProjectId);
                ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_db.Users, "UserId", "SocialSecurityNumber", timesheetentry.UserId);

                return View(timesheetentry);
            }
}
```

Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetEntries] (
    [UserId]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId]   NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [EntryDate]   DATE           NOT NULL,
    [HoursWorked] DECIMAL (8, 1) CONSTRAINT [DF_TimesheetEntries_HoursWorked] DEFAULT ((0.0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TimesheetEntries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [ProjectId] ASC, [EntryDate] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TimesheetEntries_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TimesheetEntries_Projects] FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectId])
);
```

So, how shall I make it possible for the user to change it's own unique data in the database?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The conflicting statement is

```
var timesheetentry = _db.TimesheetEntries.Find(id);
```

As you correctly mentioned, it has to do with the number of key fields. In case of your model you have to pass three elements to `Find()`.

So you have to

1. Either pass all three elements to your `Edit()` action or
2. Have a unique key with only one column (i.e. a separaty key element - not preferred in your approach)

Comment: I just passed all three elements, but I still got an error: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'entryDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit..."

public ActionResult Edit(int? id, string projectId, DateTime entryDate)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var timesheetentry = _db.TimesheetEntries.Find(id, projectId, entryDate);

Comment: This sounds like a problem passing the date from the html code. Could you debug the value of the date before calling `Find()`?

Comment: please check what's going over the channel (i.e. what the cshtml page is sending). I usually have a first look at the page source in the browser or use fiddler to see the network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you get this exception, it means you are requesting to locate a particular entity by its primary key (or group of keys). 
If you are certain your parameters to the .Find() method is the correct number of primary keys, check that your edmx model is showing the correct number of primary keys. 
 
If your edmx model is correct, there is only one other place where the error will be, that is in your database itself. Check your database and ensure you actually set any primary keys in the actual table.

> If your database table doesn't specify a primary key field, your edmx will assume each field is a key. So ensure your database and your entity model as saying the same thing.